# Doubt about Motional Emf

Tags: electromagnetism

In the derivation of a motional emf, we assume that as the conducting rod moves, the free electrons also move in the same direction as the conducting rod. However, the Tolman-Stewart Experiment showed that the motion of a conductor in one direction would lead to the movement of electrons in an opposite direction due to Inertia. Why isn't the same logic applied while analysing the motion of a rod ?

PS. If you apply this idea to analysing the motional emf you will notice that the direction of induced current will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electrons lag behind.  They aren't left behind at rest nor do they move backwards.  They still move in the same direction as the conductor, just more slowly.

In the reference frame of the conductor, the electrons move the opposite direction, but that's not what causes a motional EMF.  What we care about is the motion of the electrons relative to the magnetic field.  Relative to the field, the electrons are moving the same direction as the conductor.

The Stewart-Tolman effect is also for *accelerated* motion.  If the conductor is briefly accelerated and then continues moving at a constant speed, the electrons will eventually reach an equillibrium where they move at the same constant speed as the conductor.

Comment: Paul T., can you provide any references that are applicable to the last sentence? I am interested in learning what happens to the conducting electrons as the rod is accelerated from rest to a constant velocity.